# Debugging using MSVC

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

In GNU toolset, i can easily understand the debugging process of a cpp program. It uses an executable called GDB for the same. However, I don't really understand the debugging process in MSVC toolset. I use VSCode along with Visual Studio Build Tools.

I first believed that there is an executable like GDB in MSVC toolset which allows this to happen. However, i am not able to find one.

So what actually happens during debugging in MSVC?? In case of GDB, i can easily debug using the command line. Can i do the same by in MSVC?? What are the different executables in the toolset that allow this to happen?? Or, is there a completly different process involved??

Comment: The best way seems to use the Visual Studio IDE for that. However, regarding the executable you're asking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my question is regrading the process of "debuging" and not "how to debug";

Comment: Not sure, what you mean? Start that executable you asked  for from the command line as mentioned in the link.

Comment: MS have 5 or 6 standalone debuggers both GUI and command line - have a look at [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) .  However just Visual Studio (not code) and make your life easy.

Comment: One of my question is how to use msvc debugger from the command line. Will appreciate if you can answer it.

Comment: @YeshwinVerma Download WinDbg from the above.  You might find you already have it depending on which SDK from MS you already have installed.

Comment: @RichardCritten is it already included in the MSVC toolset

Comment: Check out [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually no standalone Debuggers shipped with MSVC toolset (I am not talking about Visual Studio, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170)).

In VSCode, the [c/c++ extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) comes with a standalone debugger called vsdbg.exe which is used to debug application compiled using the MSVC toolset.

So to debug through the command line using the MSVC toolset, one can directly call vsdbg.exe in a terminal and pass the required arguments.

The WinDBG talked about in the comments is a more universal and advance software debugging tool which can debug any code written in any language.